# Share local Wordpress site with client

Tags: macos, networking, wordpress, mamp, noip

I am using MAMP Pro to develop Wordpress sites on my local machine. I would like to show my progress to a client. MAMP Pro requires to have a third party Dynamic DNS service, I am using no-ip.com. I'm stuck on the part of port-forwarding. I am contacted to the internet via an ethernet cord, and I'm not exactly sure where to go from here.

Comment: Go to your router and apply the port forwarding. If you don't have control over the router, then you will need to speak to your IT staff and/or Internet provider. As-is there's really not enough information here for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Setup port forwarding:

1) Find out the IP of your PC or MAC where MAMP is running - let's assume this is 192.168.1.100
2) Go to your router and find port forwarding - setup forwarding form external -> 192.168.100 for port 80

3) Save the configuration and test

here is a screenshot that may help

[image]

In your case the ports below would be STArt = 80 and End = 80
[image]